# mysql syntax error on inner join statement

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the 5 last rows from two tables.

Here is the mysql statement I execute:

```
"SELECT title, thread_id
FROM threads AS t1
JOIN ON comments AS c1 ON t1.user_id = c1.user_id
 WHERE t1.user_id=".$userID
." OR c1.user_id=".$userID.
" ORDER BY thread_id DESC
LIMIT 0,5"
```

Here is the mistake:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON comments AS c1 ON t1.user_id = c1.user_id WHERE t1.user_id=1 OR c1.' at line 3

What am I doing wrong?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra ON in 3rd line. It will works.

```
"SELECT title, thread_id
FROM threads AS t1
JOIN comments AS c1 ON t1.user_id = c1.user_id
 WHERE t1.user_id=".$userID
." OR c1.user_id=".$userID.
" ORDER BY thread_id DESC
LIMIT 0,5"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a superfluous `ON` before `comments`.

Answer (score 2):

There isnt anything like `JOIN ON` should be just `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`. something like this:

```
"SELECT title, thread_id
FROM threads AS t1
JOIN comments AS c1 ON t1.user_id = c1.user_id
 WHERE t1.user_id=".$userID
." OR c1.user_id=".$userID.
" ORDER BY thread_id DESC
LIMIT 0,5"
```